# SAML and identities

Tags: saml, okta

Our customer is using Okta and is asking us to SAML-enable our app so they can access it using idnetities in Okta.

We plan to use OpenSAML to do it. So far so good.

But usually, our app has access to identities (list of users, groups/members) coming from an on-prem LDAP or AD, for example. We normally use those identities to configure authorizations in our app (give permissions to certain users to access certain ressources). Using SAML only, I don't see how to access the whole list of users/groups. And from what I understand, it's not the goal of SAML to provide it.

How is this situation typically solved? Should we try to sync the identities between Okta and our app? Is it what is called provisioning? There is Okta API, SCIM, JIT, ... Or maybe we should take a totally different approach?

Thank you!

Comment: Authorization in SAML is typically handled using the attributes the Identity Provider (in this case Okta) returns to the Service Provider (you). It will be up to you and your customer to decide which attribute(s) will be used for authorization. For example, you could ask that an attribute called `workgroups` be returned whose value is a comma-delimited list of groups the user belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to handle authorization in SAML is to use a SAML assertion to determine the authorization that a user should have. Which assertion is used and how it is will depend on your authorization model.

Note that using assertions will push the responsibility for determining authorization onto the administrator of the SAML Identity Provider, it will be up to *them* to decide who has access to what.

The ideal situation for supporting "enterprise federation" is to support SSO and Provisioning. SAML or OIDC for SSO and SCIM for provisioning.

If your software doesn't depend on an up-to-date list of users, supporting just SAML with "JIT" might be sufficient. SAML with "JIT" or "Just In Time" provisioning just means that your SAML Service Provider implementation would add users that it hasn't seen before.